# Oracle 12c REGEXP_REPLACE to extract a word from a String

Tags: oracle

I need a Regular Expression Help  
Lets say I have a String  `1.2.P Permission Level - ${Permission_manager_approval}`

I have a regular Expresion query to parse the string  
`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(:str,'(.+)\s[\$|(?:.\s\$)].*','\1')FROM DUAL;`  
by `'\1'` i get the Answer as `1.2.P Permission Level`, but When i try
`'\2'`I am getting Null
My Expected output from this query is `'Manager_approval'` Need your help on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying to extract a substring from the provided string. You can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function to achieve the same.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
             '1.2.P Permission Level - ${Permission_manager_approval}',
             'manager_([[:alnum:]]+\.?){3,4}/?') FROM DUAL;

o/p- manager_approval
```

You can also get the o/p as `Manager_approval` with the below

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (
          REGEXP_SUBSTR (
             '1.2.P Permission Level - ${Permission_manager_approval}',
             'manager_([[:alnum:]]+\.?){3,4}/?'),
          '^(\S*)',
          'Manager_approval')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: thank you Very much for your help, the Answer worked, I really Like the Second Solution you have Provided that gives me little more Flexibility.